# Is it possible to start gulp.watch without a manual gulp command?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm trying to set up a watch process for multiple people that will constantly be keeping an eye on a collection of files. I understand how to get gulp.watch set up, but I need to go a step beyond and have that watcher self-start and always be running. Starting it manually leaves room for potential user error, like someone forgetting to start it before making changes. 
Additionaly, everyone has varying numbers of the code base checked out (for concurrent dev). This watcher would either need to be aware of all those code bases, or a unique one per each code base would have to be active. Any ideas what I could do to make this as automatic as possible? This is a small part of the work environment, so I can't have it be something that needs constant maintenance by each individual user

Comment: a simple start script would be enough (runs at os bootup,) though i kinda wonder about this dev environment you are using... sounds like you have everyone working on different sets of code, but it's all being compiled and deployed to one server.. or something. seems a bit weird that you'd need to watch these files as they're working on them rather than just looking at the differences when the file is commited to version control.

Comment: The idea of watching on save is so that the dev can test their code immediately after modifying it, rather than waiting for a commit for the compilation to run.

I like the running the watch on boot up, but each dev can have multiple versions of code base that they work on tasks concurrently, so this auto-launched watcher would need to be aware (or be set up manually) to watch each code base. I would like to avoid as much manual configuration down the line as possible

Comment: To me it seems like you're trying too hard to make things easy. Is it not easy enough for the dev to type "gulp dev" when they start working on a particular project? That's what we do,

Comment: In our case gulp dev builds the project, opens up a browser tab targeting the project, and then watches for changes. When css is changed, css is re-compiled and injected into the browser tab. When js is changed, the project is re-built  and the browser tab is refreshed.